# Radon-Nikodym derivative of Measures

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Im having some trouble reconciling what I thought I learned about RN Derivatives as they relate to probability measures [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem), [lecture notes](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~doksum/STAT709/n709-5.pdf) with this [blog post](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/information/information_geometry_6.html) by John Baez mentioning it as it relates to KL divergences.

Specifically, when John says:

> And by the way, in case you're wondering, the $d$ here doesn't
>   actually mean much: we're just so brainwashed into wanting a $dx$ in
>   our integrals that people often use $d$ for a measure even though the
>   simpler notation $\mu$ might be more logical. So, the function:
>
> $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}$
>
> is really just a ratio of probability measures, but people call it a
>   Radon-Nikodym derivative, because it looks like a derivative (and in
>   some important examples it actually is).

It seems to me that there is some deep intuition Im missing here. Could anyone please elaborate on this perspective?

Specifically: I'm asking:

- To what degree is an RN derivative *really* just a ratio of probability measures?
- If isn't technically a ratio of two measures, is it helpful to think of it sometimes as being that ratio? In what instances?

Thanks!

Comment: Your third link is just wikipedia again. Also, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I think the $d$ represents a change in the normal sense of detivative and tis changing measure works for me..also the fact it appears in the area of option pricing derivatives adds a bonus to it ;).

Comment: The change measure only allowed if the event can occur in both probablity measures..so if some think has a proability as outlined in one measure then it must also have a probability in the other.

Comment: @avid19 sorry about that I fixed it. I am just looking for the "intuition" behind John's description of the RN derivative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Radon-Nikodym “derivative” is an a.e. define concept. Suppose $(X,S)$ is a measure space and $\mu,\nu$ are finite measures on $(X,S)$ with $\mu\ll\nu$, then the theorem is:

**Theorem.** There exists $f\in L^{1}(X,\nu)$ a non-negative real-valued function, with $\mu(A)=\int_{x\in A} f(x)~\nu(dx)$ for all $A\in S$.

There are all sorts of generalisations (to $\sigma$-finite, signed, and complex-valued measures, etc.). This is the theorem/lemma in its simplest form. It is easy to show, that if $f,f'$ satisfy the theorem, then $f'=f$ $\nu$-a.e. (and thus also $\mu$-a.e.). Thus the function is “unique” warranting the definite article.

Since it effectively follows, that $\int g~d\mu=\int gf~d\nu$ for $g$ in $L^{1}(X,\mu)$, on may apply the nomenclature "$d\mu=f d\nu$", so that the notation $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}$ for $f$ is an intuitive name. Since $f$ has the said property, it follows, that it is an “effective” derivative.

---

Here an outline of the proof/construction:

**Lemma.** Let $\sigma$ be a signed mass on $X$ (this means, countably additive and finite). Then there is a measurable set $A\subseteq X$ satisfying $(\forall{B\in S})~B\subseteq A\Rightarrow\sigma(B)\geq 0$
and $(\forall{B\in S})~B\subseteq X\setminus A\Rightarrow\sigma(B)\leq 0$. Thus $\sigma=\sigma^{+}-\sigma^{-}$, whereby $\sigma^{+}=\sigma\mid_{A}$ and $\sigma^{-}=\sigma\mid_{X\setminus A}$ are non-negative finite measures with disjoint support. Moreover, any such decomposition of $\sigma$ is of this form and $A$ is unique $\sigma$-a.e.

**Proof of Theorem.** (Sketch). Let $A_{r}\in S$ be as in the Lemma for the signed measure $\sigma_{r}:=r\nu-\mu$ for each $r\in\mathbb{Q}$. Consider now two rationals $r<r'$. Then $\sigma_{r'}=\sigma_{r}+(r'-r)\nu$. Let $B=A_{r}\setminus A_{r'}$. It holds per definition of the decomposition(s), that

$$0\geq\sigma_{r'}(B)=\sigma_{r}(B)+(r'-r)\nu(B)\geq 0+(r'-r)\nu(B),$$

thus $\nu(B)=0$. Thus $A_{r}\subseteq^{\ast}_{\nu}A_{r'}$. Replacing $A_{r}$ with the thus $\nu$-a.e. equivalent set $\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q},q\leq r}A_{q}$, it can be assumed that $(A_{q})_{q\in(\mathbb{Q},<)}$ ist a monotone increasing family of measurable sets.

Consider finally the map $f:x\in X\mapsto \inf\{r\in\mathbb{Q}:x\in A_{r}\}\in[-\infty,\infty]$. This can readily be shown to be well-defined, measureable and $\nu$-a.e. $>\infty$. Let $B\in S$. For all reals, $r<r'$, it holds that $f^{-1}[r,r')=A_{r'}\setminus A_{r}$ $\nu$-a.e. and thus also $\mu$-a.e.; it therefore holds that

\begin{align}
\int_{B\cap f^{-1}[r,r')}f~d\nu-\mu(B\cap f^{-1}[r,r'))
&\geq r\nu(B\cap A_{r'}\setminus A_{r})-\mu(B\cap A_{r'}\setminus A_{r})\\
&= (r-r')\nu(B\cap A_{r'}\setminus A_{r})
+\sigma_{r'}(B\cap A_{r'}\setminus A_{r})\\
&\geq -(r'-r)\nu(B\cap A_{r'}\setminus A_{r}+0\\
&= -(r'-r)\nu(B\cap f^{-1}[r,r')).\\
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\int_{B\cap f^{-1}[r,r')}f~d\nu-\mu(B\cap f^{-1}[r,r'))
&\leq r'\nu(B\cap A_{r'}\setminus A_{r})-\mu(B\cap A_{r'}\setminus A_{r})\\
&= (r'-r)\nu(B\cap A_{r'}\setminus A_{r})
+\sigma_{r}(B\cap A_{r'}\setminus A_{r})\\
&\leq (r'-r)\nu(B\cap A_{r'}\setminus A_{r}+0\\
&= (r'-r)\nu(B\cap f^{-1}[r,r')).\\
\end{align}

Thus

$$\left|\int_{B\cap f^{-1}[r,r')}f~d\nu-\mu(B\cap f^{-1}[r,r'))\right| \leq (r'-r)~\nu(B\cap f^{-1}[r,r')).$$

It follows that, decomposing $B$ into countably many preimages under $f$ of sufficiently small intervals of the real line, that

$$\left|\int_{B}f~d\nu-\mu(B)\right|\leq\varepsilon\nu(B)$$

for all $\varepsilon>0$. Thus $\int_{B}f~d\nu=\mu(B)$ for all $B\in S$ (in particular $f\in L^{1}(\nu)$).

**Q.e.d.**

---

**Interpreting the derivative (aside from its application).**

The construction in the proof allows one to describe the derivative. It holds for $\varepsilon>0$ and reals $a<b$ with $|b-a|<\varepsilon$ and $\nu$-a.e. $x\in X$ that $a\leq\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}(x)<b$ if and only if $x\in A_{b}\setminus A_{a}=:B$, which means the set of such $x$ constitutes a set $B$ with $b\nu(B)-\mu(B)=\sigma_{b}(B)\geq 0$ and $a\nu(B)-\mu(B)=\sigma_{a}(B)\leq 0$.

It immediately follows, that either $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}$ is $\nu$-a.e. not in $[a,b)$, or else $a\leq\frac{\mu(B)}{\mu(B)}\leq b$. Thus for $|b-a|<\varepsilon$ small

$$\left|\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}(x)-\frac{\mu(B)}{\nu(B)}\right|<\varepsilon$$

for  $\nu$-a.e. $x\in B:=\{y\in X:\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}(y)\in[a,b)\}$.

Or in other words: let $f=\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}$. Then for $\nu$-a.e. $x\in X$ it holds that $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}(x)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^{+}}\frac{\mu(f^{-1}U_{\varepsilon,x})}{\nu(f^{-1}U_{\varepsilon,x})}$, where $U_{\varepsilon,x}\subseteq\mathbf{R}$ the $\varepsilon$-interval around $f(x)\in\mathbf{R}$.

Comment: “is really just a ratio of probability measures” — sorry, this is just far too oversimplified, it is at most an highly localised ratio of measures. But certainly NOT equal to $\mu(w)/\nu(w)$ for $w\in\Omega$. The former does not even make any sense, as the notation should be $\mu(\{w\})$ and this is typically $0$. At most one may consider $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}(w)$ as a limit of $\mu(A)/\nu(A)$ for certain measurable sets $A$ $\ldots$ but even this is wrong-headed. Measures are really messy. To prove RN, one applies a decomposition result for signed measures to $\mu-q\nu$ for all $q\in\mathbf{R}$.

Comment: Thomas, Is  this comment meant to address @Simon's answer?

Comment: Diego, I am commenting on what “John says” as well as Simon Rigbys (former) remark.

Comment: thank you very much for your thorough answer. Particularly useful for me was the "interpreting" section!

Answer (score 4):

The Radon-Nikodym derivative is a thing which re-weights the probabilities, i.e. it is a ratio of two probability densities or masses. It is used when moving from one measure to another, for whatever reason you have to do so. So, say $X$ is a random variable and you want to work out $\mathbb{E}_\lambda[X]$ - i.e.the expectation of $X$ in $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\lambda)$ - but you know more about the measure $\mu$. If you have the RD derivative $d\lambda/d\mu$ then you can find that $\mathbb{E}_\lambda[X] = \mathbb{E}_\mu[\frac{d\lambda}{d\mu}X]$. This is what your Proposition 1.7 is saying I think.

I'm not sure what examples the quoted author is referring to where the Radon-Nikodym derivative really **is** a derivative. This might be interesting to learn.

Comment: Is the RD derivative you write about somehow related to the Radon-Nikodym derivative?

Comment: @GEdgar I think they're the same thing

Comment: @Stanley I think this problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524383/probability-density-and-expected-value has to do with the Radon-Nikodym derivative, although I've never heard it called that. Can you please help me with it? Thank you.